# macbook thermal problems

Tags: warranty

I have a macbook air 2018 edition which has bad thermals from long usage which makes my screen flicker as a thin line on the very bottom edge of the screen. If my warranty is over, will apple still fix this issue for free? Because I do not understand why using a computer for a long time say max 5 hours a day will cause damage to the hardware.

Edit: here is a  picture 
of my issue

[image]

There are these lines on the bottom edge that was not here yesterday, but here when I turned on the computer this morning.

Comment: How did you determine "bad thermals" was the cause of your screen damage?  Without actual seeing the damage, we can't even begin to speculate what the cause and potential solution could be; can you take a photo and post? Finally, we're independent of Apple and cannot speak to what they will/won't do with respect to warranty coverage.

Comment: Oh the thermals comes from my research on some other forums which has similar issues like mine seeing the images posted there. But yes I will upload an image.

Comment: Take that with a *ton* of salt.  The amount of heat you would need to generate to cause damage to an LCD would far exceed the thermal limits of the CPU.  In other words, your CPU would shutdown automatically to protect itself long before your LCD would sustain damage.

Comment: From the picture, you have a physically damaged LCD and it has nothing to do with "thermals."

Comment: I uploaded the image, i am so confused because it was fine yesterday and I treat my macbook in a pretty good way. I dont know why it is doing this to me now ...

Comment: Damage happens even in the best of circumstances.

Comment: But how are you so sure it is not thermals which caused the hardware damage to some of the cables inside the macbook which causes that display?

Comment: 1)  Thermal damage wouldn't be a perfectly straight line.  The laws of thermodynamics (fluids, and air is a fluid) means it would look like splotches.  2)  See my comment re:  the CPU shutting down  3) That much heat through cables would melt the cable before it melted a *glass* medium not attached to it.

Comment: Ok so mentioning thermodynamics is completely unnecessary here. Those laws describe how the entropies change in a system, nothing to do with motion of fluids, besides i dont imply thermals would cause a straight line, i meant excessive heating to the laptop might damage other components such as cables or graphics card which may cause such display error.

Comment: And part of that system would be... a fluid.  You don't need to imply it, the evidence you presented *was* a straight line.  Why would excessive heat only "might" cause damage to other components, but "certainly" cause damage to the LCD?  And once again...the heat required to do this damage would literally destroy your CPU.

Comment: I have to agree with @Allan here. Also, I had exact line(s) that you show in the picture, which came from physical damage.

Comment: I dont see the relationship between how thermodynamics would lead to splotches occurring to begin with as that was not what i was implying. So I went to the apple store and they said that the new apple macbook air models had overheating problems or bad thermal cycles which caused the diffuser sheets to detach partially on the edge of the screens. Getting it replaced for free.